# unable to post data to database with httpurlconnection even though there is data in the java side

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

This is my php script. I have been trying to post data to mysql server using php script. The data is successfully added to the register function. There is no problem with my url connection as well. What seems to be the problem?

```
<?php
include ('classes/functions.php');
    if(isset($_POST['product_id'])){
        $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];

        $insert_order = "INSERT INTO orders (product_id) values  
 ('$product_id')";

        $run_order = mysqli_query($con, $insert_order);

        if($run_order){
            echo"<script>alert('Order Successfully!')</script>";
        }
    }
 ?>
```

This is my java script.

```
 public final class confirm extends Context {

private static final String REGISTER_URL = 
"http://192.168.43.214/apexStore2/confirm.php";

public static void register(String id) {
    class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
         ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }
  @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put("product_id",params[0]);

            String result = sendPost(REGISTER_URL,data);

            return  result;
        }
    }

    RegisterUser ru = new RegisterUser();
    ru.execute(id);
}
public static String sendPost(String requestURL,
                              HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {

    URL url;
    String response = " ";
    try {
        url = new URL(requestURL);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" +
                    Integer.toString(getPostDataString(postDataParams).
    getBytes().length));
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);


        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));
        System.out.println("wei" + getPostDataString(postDataParams));
        Log.d(getPostDataString(postDataParams), "onCreate()");
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new  
    InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            response = br.readLine();
        }
        else {
            response="Error Registering";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}

private static String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) 
throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this on an emulator or alternatively on a device? Either way I think it would be helpful to confirm that the device is on the correct network to see your internal ip of 192.168.43.214, you may need to use your external IP especially if you are connecting though a data connection. Other than that, what is the output of the android log?

Comment: im using a mobile phone. This ip is tested no problem as there are other function using this ip and it works.

Comment: the android log just show the value that i pass. but it doesn't show successful

Comment: Can you post the output please? Also is the server getting any connection from the client at all, or nothing? I am not seeing anything improper with your code, but it's very difficult to debug without more information on the output or alternatively more information on the behaviour.